# Trouble using grammar with rakudo perl6

Tags: raku, rakudo

The simplest grammar usage gives me complation error.

```
use v6;
grammar Foo {
   token bar { \w+ }
}
say 'abc' ~~ /<Foo::bar>/;
```

Invoked like `src/rakudo/perl6 simple.p6`, it fails with

```
regex assertion not terminated by angle bracket at line 7, near "::bar>/;\n"
...
```

I tried a number of known-to-work examples with similar results, so I suspect that my perl6 setup is incorrect.

If you use grammar with perl6, please show me your setup. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry; your error message contains two clues (`line 7`, `::bar`) that the code you've pasted is not enough to diagnose your problem. There's just not enough information to understand your problem.

Apart from that, you have a mismatched closing parenthesis in the last line of the code you did post, and you haven't declared the `<Foo::bar>`.

I don't think your Perl 6 setup is incorrect, for what it's worth. There's nothing in what you've written to indicate that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the syntax error with the example. I have updated the code.  


Going back to (#25 "Minneapolis") from snapshot from February fixed the error. The above code now runs:
rakudo-2010-01/parrot_install/bin/perl6 simple.p6
abc

Thanks for your hard work on perl6 and I am looking forward to using it.

Answer (score 2):

**Rakudo 2010.02 release (#26 "Amsterdam")** has a regression that breaks module import.
Use **Rakudo 2010-01 release (#25 "Minneapolis")** instead.
download page is here: http://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/downloads